# Exclude 0 and range in number field using regex

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have an input field in which only numbers may be entered and also only the numbers 1 to 5000 are allowed.

I have already excluded letters and the number 0 but I am not able to exclude all numbers from 5001 to 9999.

This is the code I have so far to exclude all letters and the number 0.

```
function validate_num(formdata) {
    formdata.value = formdata.value.replace(/^[0]+$/, '' );
} 

function validate_num(formdata) {
    formdata.value = formdata.value.replace(/\D/, '' );
}
```

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Answer (score 1):

HTML input:

```
<input type="number" min="1" max="5000" maxlength="4" oninput="allowNumbers(this);" onblur="checkRange(this);">
```

JS:

```
function allowNumbers(input) {
    input.value = input.value.replace(/[^0-9]/, '');
}
function checkRange(input) {
   if(input.value < input.min) {
      input.value = input.min;
   }
   if(input.value > input.max) {
      input.value = input.max;
   }
}
```

Comment: Why not use the min and max attributes in the test? No need to pass it. Anyway a pattern might be a cleaner solution

Comment: Yeah but the Task id to do it with RegEx but thanks for your help :D

Comment: Oh and i have to say if yout type in the number if its bigger than 5000 it gets directly deleted

Comment: What are you what to say with taht comment?